# Can't generate ligatures with LuaLaTeX under MacTeX2014 and MacTeX2015 when using certain fonts

Tags: fonts, luatex, ligatures, opentype, mac

(Remark: This question was posted originally when the big news, TeX-wise, was the impending transition from TeXLive2013 to TeXLive2014. Since the issue identified in this posting persists in TeXLive2015, I've chosen to update the posting's title accordingly.)

Consider the following MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\listfiles
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,Rare}]{Hoefler Text}
\begin{document}
ff fi fl ffi ffl fj ct st
\end{document}
```

When compiling this program on my system (MacOSX 10.9.2, MacTeX2013, luatex 0.76.0) under LuaLaTeX, I get the expected result, i.e., all ligatures are generated correctly:

[image]

However, if I switch to TeXLive2014 ([currently in advanced beta](http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html)), which employs luatex 0.79.1, no ligatures are created:

[image]

This problem doesn't arise under TeXLive2014 if I (i) compile the MWE under XeLaTeX instead of LuaLaTeX or (ii) use a different font, say, `Adobe Garamond Pro`, `Garamond Premier Pro`, or `Latin Modern Roman`. (Of course, the latter font doesn't feature ligatures for fj, ct, and st, but ligatures *are* generated for ff, fi, fl, ffi, and ffl.)

Is there a setting that needs to be tweaked to enable ligatures when using `Hoefler Text`?

For completeness, here are the files used by the LuaLaTeX/TeXLive2014 run:

```
LuaTeX, Version beta-0.79.1 (TeX Live 2014/dev) (rev 4971)  (format=lualatex 2014.4.24) 

 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
fontspec.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2014/01/07 v4646 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
 l3names.sty    2014/01/04 v4640 L3 Namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty    2014/01/04 v4640 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
  luatex.sty    2010/03/09 v0.4 LuaTeX basic definition package (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
luatex-loader.sty    2010/03/09 v0.4 Lua module loader (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
l3basics.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Basic definitions
 l3expan.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Argument expansion
    l3tl.sty    2013/12/27 v4625 L3 Token lists
   l3seq.sty    2013/12/14 v4623 L3 Sequences and stacks
   l3int.sty    2013/08/02 v4583 L3 Integers
 l3quark.sty    2013/12/14 v4623 L3 Quarks
   l3prg.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Control structures
 l3clist.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Comma separated lists
 l3token.sty    2013/08/25 v4587 L3 Experimental token manipulation
  l3prop.sty    2013/12/14 v4623 L3 Property lists
   l3msg.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Messages
  l3file.sty    2013/10/13 v4596 L3 File and I/O operations
  l3skip.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Dimensions and skips
  l3keys.sty    2013/12/08 v4614 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
    l3fp.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Floating points
   l3box.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental boxes
l3coffins.sty    2013/12/14 v4624 L3 Coffin code layer
 l3color.sty    2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support
l3luatex.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
l3candidates.sty    2014/01/06 v4643 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
  xparse.sty    2013/12/31 v4634 L3 Experimental document command parser
luaotfload.sty    2014/02/05 v2.4-3 OpenType layout system
luatexbase.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Resource management for the LuaTeX macro progr
ammer
luatexbase-compat.sty    2011/05/24 v0.4 Compatibility tools for LuaTeX
luatexbase-modutils.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Module utilities for LuaTeX
luatexbase-loader.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Lua module loader for LuaTeX
luatexbase-regs.sty    2011/05/24 v0.4 Registers allocation for LuaTeX
luatexbase-attr.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Attributes allocation for LuaTeX
luatexbase-cctb.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Catcodetable allocation for LuaTeX
luatexbase-mcb.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Callback management for LuaTeX
fontspec-patches.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

fixltx2e.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
fontspec-luatex.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu2enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu2lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many othe
r characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu2lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
fontspec.cfg
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

Comment: If I compare the file list after compiling with the 2013 and 2014 versions of LuaTeX, I get no difference. There's no difference in time stamps for the `.lua` files accompanying `luaotfload.sty`. But I can confirm the ligatures don't show up with the 2014/dev version.

Comment: Maybe a caching issue? Did you run ``luaotfload-tool --cache=erase`` after the update to tl 2014?

Comment: @phg - Many thanks for this suggestion. I tried it, but no luck, i.e., the ligatures still aren't being produced under TeXLive2014/LuaTeX 0.79.1 after the cache has been removed.

Comment: @Mico: Ah, OK. It was worth a try, though. Btw. thanks for being brave and running the pretest -- a Luaotfload update is coming soon.

Comment: @phg - Thanks. In the meantime, I've been pointed to [this thread](http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2013-December/004657.html), dated December 2013. In the posting, the author reports encountering some problems very similar to the ones I've reported above, but with `Didot` and `Baskerville`, two other fonts which make use of AAT (Appled Advanced Technologies) font capabilities, but only after switching to luatex 0.78. In a follow-up message to that posting, Khaled Hosny expressed an expectation (hope?) that things would get fixed via an update to `luaotfload`...

Comment: @Mico If those fonts are in fact AAT fonts then Luaotfload can’t help you -- the FontForge libraries are part of LuaTeX so we’re limited to whatever falls out of the ``fontloader`` library. If the issue is reproducible with regular OpenType fonts then you hit a bug.

Comment: @phg - The font files in question, on my system at least, are `/Library/Fonts/Hoefler Text.ttc(HoeflerText-Regular:0)`, `/Library/Fonts/Didot.ttc(Didot:0)`, and `/Library/Fonts/Baskerville.ttc(Baskerville:3)`. How can one determine if they use AAT features? Is it significant that all three files have extension `.ttc` rather than, say, `.otf`? One reason why I'm speculating that the AAT (non-) support issue is in play is because the MWE compiles fine under XeLaTeX.

Comment: @Mico Sorry I can’t help you here. I’ve never even seen an AAT font. My best advice is to run standard tools on the file, e.g. ``otfinfo``, ``ttx``, or Fontforge itself.

Comment: @phg - Thanks for these suggestions, I'll try them. And I'll look forward to the next version of `luaotfload`. :-)

Comment: @phg The fact is that with the previous version of LuaTeX the ligature worked and the font files are exactly the same.  So this is a regression.

Comment: @phg - The problem first noted in this posting still persists, four months later. At the time I wrote this posting, I was working with the pre-release version of MacTeX2014 (which already included luatex 0.79.1). All style and other files used to run the MWE -- except for the binary itself -- were identical across the then-current versions of MacTeX2013 and MacTeX2014. So why doesn't it follow that it is something about the luatex binary that's at the heart of the problem?

Comment: @Mico is there anything new to report here?

Comment: @PaulGessler - I've posted an answer, in which I show how ligatures may be restored by creating (and loading) a so-called feature file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the advent of MacTeX2014 and continuing in MacTeX2015 -- and likely to persist into the indefinite future :-( -- Lua(La)TeX can no longer directly access certain font features, such as ligatures, *if* the font is a system font whose ligature-related properties are AAT-encoded and not OpenType-encoded. `Hoefler Text`, `Didot`, and `Baskerville` are three such fonts. (In contrast, XeLaTeX continues to be able to access ligature-related features directly.)

By setting up one more or "feature files" that spell out which ligature substitutions should be performed, it is possible to restore ligatures when working with version of LuaLaTeX more recent than version 0.77.

The output of the code shown below has the following characteristics: the first row is generated *before* the feature file is loaded; note that it's lacking ligatures even though the option `Ligatures=Common` option was specified when the font (`Hoefler Text` in this case) was loaded via a `\setmainfont` statement. The second row, which is generated *after* the feature file is loaded via an `\addfontfeature` instruction, contains all the expected ligatures.

Aside: (i) The example uses the `filecontents` package to be self-contained. In practice, all one needs to do is to create the feature file "addligs.fea" *once* and store it in a directory that's searched by the TeX distribution. (ii) The feature file shown here features (pun intended...) quite a few ligature substitutions, since `Hoefler Text` features lots and lots of ligatures. For other, less feature-rich, fonts, the "standard five" ligatures -- `ff`, `fi`, `fl`, `ffi`, and `ffl` -- may be all that you need to take of.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{addligs.fea}
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;
# Ligatures
feature liga {
    sub f f   by f_f;
    sub f i   by f_i;
    sub f j   by f_j;
    sub f k   by f_k;
    sub f l   by f_l;
    sub f f i by f_f_i;
    sub f f l by f_f_l;
    sub s t   by s_t;
    sub c t   by c_t;
} liga;
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=Common]{Hoefler Text}

\newcommand\wordlist{off fit fjord Kafka fly office baffle stop act}

\begin{document}
\wordlist

\addfontfeature{FeatureFile=addligs.fea}
\wordlist
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Here's a slightly more sophisticated example, which uses two different feature files depending on whether the font face is upright or italic. It makes use of the ability of `fontspec` to specify different features for Upright, Bold, Italic, and BoldItalic font faces. The separate treatment of the italic and non-italic cases is necessary because `Hoefler Text` features additional ligatures (esp. for "sp" and "Th") just for the italic font faces.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{AddligsHoeflerUpright.fea}
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;
# Ligatures
feature liga {
    sub f b   by f_b;
    sub f f   by f_f;
    sub f h   by f_h;
    sub f i   by f_i;
    sub f j   by f_j;
    sub f k   by f_k;
    sub f l   by f_l;
    sub f f b by f_f_b;
    sub f f h by f_f_h;
    sub f f i by f_f_i;
    sub f f k by f_f_k;
    sub f f l by f_f_l;
    sub c t   by c_t;
    sub s t   by s_t;
} liga;
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{AddligsHoeflerItalic.fea}
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;
# Ligatures
feature liga {
    sub f b   by f_b;
    sub f f   by f_f;
    sub f h   by f_h;
    sub f i   by f_i;
    sub f j   by f_j;
    sub f k   by f_k;
    sub f l   by f_l;
    sub f f b by f_f_b;
    sub f f h by f_f_h;
    sub f f i by f_f_i;
    sub f f k by f_f_k;
    sub f f l by f_f_l;
    sub c t   by c_t;
    sub s t   by s_t;
    sub s p   by s_p;
    sub T h   by T_h;
    sub a s   by a_s;
} liga;
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}[
    Ligatures          = {Common,Rare},
    ItalicFont         = Hoefler Text Italic,
    BoldFont           = Hoefler Text Black,
    BoldItalicFont     = Hoefler Text Black Italic]

\newcommand\words{fb ff fh fi fj fk fl ffb ffh ffk ffl ct st, sp Th}

\begin{document}

ligatures missing:

\words\par
\textbf{\words}\par
\textit{\words}\par
\textbf{\textit{\words}}

\addfontfeature{%
    UprightFeatures    = {FeatureFile=AddligsHoeflerUpright.fea},
    BoldFeatures       = {FeatureFile=AddligsHoeflerUpright.fea},
    ItalicFeatures     = {FeatureFile=AddligsHoeflerItalic.fea},
    BoldItalicFeatures = {FeatureFile=AddligsHoeflerItalic.fea}}

\medskip   
ligatures restored/activated:

\words\par
\textbf{\words}\par
\textit{\words}\par
\textbf{\textit{\words}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't perhaps this answer mention that the ligatures are missing because they're seleceted by AAT features rather than OpenType features?

Comment: @Sverre - I'm not sure what you're driving at. Does it matter -- from the point of view of a MacTeX user who runs an up-to-date version of Lua(La)TeX (i.e., version 0.77 or later) and would like to use ligatures in his/her documents -- that the ligatures are missing in some (but not all!) MacOS system fonts because they're encoded as AAT features? Does this maybe make a difference for the way the feature file should be set up? Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: I would say yes. In the question, it's not clear what kind of fonts have this problem. But in the following discussion, it did become clear. So from a user perspective, I think it is relevant to know that this problem would only arise with some MacOS fonts with AAT features. From the current answer, it would appear that the problem would appear for unknown reasons with any type of font. I'm not saying you need to change anything in your answer - but perhaps add something in the beginning about what kind of fonts this problem afflicts, and why.

Comment: @Sverre - Thanks for this clarification. I'll add a sentence or two to the question.

Comment: Good. Now I knew I had seen @KhaledHosny explain somewhere why LuaTeX stopped supporting AAT, and it's actually to your [follow-up question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198061/9077) to this one. Maybe both should now have a comment/answer linking to each other, with this thread linking to the other for a discussion about AAT features and why they're not supported in LuaTeX, and the other thread linking to this one about how to compensate for it with the use of feature files?