# Adobe Garamond Pro in LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, adobe, mathdesign

At first, everytime I apply any of the lines  below

```
\usepackage[adobe-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[Adobe Garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[mdpgd]{mathdesign}
```

my code compiles but does not produce a pdf document. After some troubleshooting, I found out that it doesn't work when I set something to **bold** style.

I then installed the opentype fonts as indicated in the documentation of `mathdesign` package (see http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathdesign/). Relevant files are

```
AGaramondPro-Regular.otf 
AGaramondPro-Italic.otf
AGaramondPro-Semibold.otf
AGaramondPro-SemiboldItalic.otf
```

Fortunately, it worked! However, another problem arose; the ligatures don't work!! For example,

[image: this image]

is supposed to be `may be effective in`, but the `ff` ligature turned into a box. What can I do to make the ligatures work?

Comment: Can you add a Minimal Working Example so we can see the context, please? Not everyone will have the fonts, of course, but if somebody does, your code should enable them to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173566/cant-generate-ligatures-with-lualatex-under-texlive-2014-when-using-certain-fon) the problem you're seeing? Are you using LuaTeX rather than XeTeX?