# Adobe Garamond Pro & ligatures

Tags: luatex, small-caps, ligatures, garamond

I need to use Adobe Garamond Pro on LaTeX to build an editorial layout. I installed the Adamond Garamond Pro font files (Regular, Bold, Italic, BoldItalic, SemiBold, SemiBoldItalic) on my computer (MacBook Air 2021) and try to use it with TexLive 2021, compiling in LuaLaTeX.  Unfortunately, there are some problems with ligatures (mainly ff) and with small capitals which are replaced by some symbol:

[image: An example of I obtain when compiling in LuaLaTeX]

I also tried the solution mentionned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220427/adobe-garamond-pro-in-latex/655598#655598) but without success. I am a beginner in LuaLaTeX so maybe there is something wrong with my installation... Here is a exemple (that I compiled on my computer and on Overleaf) :

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode


\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
%\setmainfont[ Ligatures={TeX, Common}]{AGaramondPro-Regular}[
%    BoldFont       = AGaramondPro-Bold,
%     ItalicFont     = AGaramondPro-Italic,
%     BoldItalicFont = AGaramondPro-BoldItalic]
\addfontfeatures{RawFeature = +smcp}
\addfontfeatures{RawFeature = -liga}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[mdpgd]{mathdesign}% thanks to Ulrike Fisher

\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\textsc{Essai en petites capitales}

ff fi fl ffi ffl fj ct st

\end{document}
```

Thank you very muchfor you help.

Answer (score 1):

With the two answers above, it works (with ligatures, small caps and maths !). Here is the result:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode


\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
Extension=.otf,
UprightFont= *-Regular,
BoldFont       = *-Bold,
ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
]{AGaramondPro}

  \addfontfeatures{RawFeature=-liga}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math}
\usepackage{mathtools} % contient amsmath 
\usepackage{bm}        % 


\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{csquotes}


\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
    
    
  
    \textsc{Essai en petites capitales}
    
    ff fi fl ffi ffl fj ct st
    

    
    \section{Conformal maps}
    
    Le premier principe en \textbf{système ouvert} se présente
    sous la forme de l'équation \eqref{eq:PPSO}
    suivante :
    \begin{equation}
        \label{eq:PPSO}
        \frac{dU}{dt} +\dot{m}_s h(T_s,P_s)
        -\dot{m}_e h(T_e,P_e) = \dot{W}_u + \dot{Q}
    \end{equation}
    
    \begin{equation*}
        \left(
        \iint\limits_{\partial\Sigma}\rho \bm{v}\cdot\bm{n} dS
        \right)
    \end{equation*}
    
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{split}
            (a+b)^3 & = (a+b) (a+b)^2 \\
            & = (a+b)(a^2+2ab+b^2) \\
            & = a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3 \\
        \end{split}
    \end{equation}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the MikTeX distribution.

I installed Adobe fonts manually - copied the `*.otf` files to the directory:

`C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts\opentype\adobe\AdobeGaramondPro`

and executed `Refresh file name database` from the GUI.

This code generates the ligatures correctly.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{AdobeGaramondPro}

\addfontfeatures{RawFeature = +smcp}
\addfontfeatures{RawFeature = -liga}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[mdpgd]{mathdesign}

\usepackage{mathtools} % contient amsmath 
\usepackage{bm}        % 

\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
    
    \textsc{Essai en petites capitales}
    
    ff fi fl ffi ffl fj ct st
    
    \section{Conformal maps}
    
    Le premier principe en \textbf{système ouvert} se présente
    sous la forme de l'équation \eqref{eq:PPSO}
    suivante :
    \begin{equation}
        \label{eq:PPSO}
        \frac{dU}{dt} +\dot{m}_s h(T_s,P_s)
        -\dot{m}_e h(T_e,P_e) = \dot{W}_u + \dot{Q}
    \end{equation}
    
    \begin{equation*}
        \left(
        \iint\limits_{\partial\Sigma}\rho \bm{v}\cdot\bm{n} dS
        \right)
    \end{equation*}
    
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{split}
            (a+b)^3 & = (a+b) (a+b)^2 \\
            & = (a+b)(a^2+2ab+b^2) \\
            & = a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3 \\
        \end{split}
    \end{equation}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! On my computer the mathdesign package do not work... but by replacing it by \usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math}, it is perfect if I combine with the solution given by Daniel below :-)

Answer (score 0):

In order to test your file, I downloaded Adobe Garamond Pro from wFonts.com and unzipped it in my current folder together with your file.

The following test file

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
Extension=.otf,
UprightFont= *-Regular,
BoldFont       = *-Bold,
ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
]{AGaramondPro}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\textsc{Essai en petites capitales}

ff fi fl ffi ffl fj ct st

\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+dlig}
ct st

\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=-liga}
ff fi fl ffi ffl fj
\end{document}
```

compiled with lualatex (TL2022) produces this output which seems correct.
The font doesn't seem to have the s_t ligature though.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution! It works also for me... and by testing Simon's proposal above, I understood that the problem came from the mathdesign package! I replaced it by : \usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math} and it works perfectly! Thanks again!

Comment: @JennyB The `mathdesign` package is meant for pdflatex, not for lualatex or xelatex: it prints type1 fonts only.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this information !